# Switch d3 donut arc on selection

Tags: javascript, css, html, d3.js, svg

I have more than one donut in my page, each donut will have a thinner portion (like unfilled) and another arc colored.

When user clicks on the colored arc, it should have a white border. And if user selects other arc (unfilled) the unfilled area get filled with color, changes the width like the other one and will have border, same time the filled one gets unfilled. To summarize the arc colored portion should get switched on selection.

Can I achieve this by applying class/styles? In one page there should be only one arc selected at a time, all other selections will be cleared.

```
// data
var dataset = [{
  color: "#5FC5EA",
  value: 70
}, {
  color: "transparent",
  value: 30
}];

// size
var width = 460,
  z
height = 300,
  radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;

var pie = d3.layout.pie()
  .sort(null).value(function(d) {
    return d.value;
  });

// thin arc
var arc1 = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 20)
  .outerRadius(radius - 11);

// main arc
var arc = d3.svg.arc()
  .innerRadius(radius - 30)
  .outerRadius(radius);

// set svg
var svg = d3.select("#d3-setup-donut").append("svg")
  .attr("class", 'donut-chart')
  .attr("width", width)
  .attr("height", height)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 2 + "," + height / 2 + ")")
  .on('mouseout', function() {
    d3.selectAll('.donut-tooltip').style('display', 'none');
  });

// tooltip
var div = d3.select("body")
  .append("div")
  .attr("class", "donut-tooltip");

// draw thinner arc
var path = svg.selectAll(".background")
  .data(pie([{
    color: "#222427",
    value: 1
  }]))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "background")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
  })
  .attr("d", arc1)
  .on('click', function(d, i) {
    //
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    var mouseVal = d3.mouse(this);
    div.style("display", "none");
    div.html(d.data.label + " : " + d.value)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 40) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 35) + "px")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("display", "block");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    div.html(" ").style("display", "none");
  });

// draw main arc
var path = svg.selectAll(".foreground")
  .data(pie(dataset))
  .enter().append("path")
  .attr("class", "foreground")
  .attr("fill", function(d, i) {
    return d.data.color;
  })
  .attr("d", arc)
  .on('click', function(d, i) {
    d3.select(this)
      .classed('selected', true);
  })
  .on("mousemove", function(d, i) {
    var mouseVal = d3.mouse(this);
    div.style("display", "none");
    div.html(d.data.label + " : " + d.value)
      .style("left", (d3.event.pageX - 40) + "px")
      .style("top", (d3.event.pageY - 55) + "px")
      .style("opacity", 1)
      .style("display", "block");
  })
  .on("mouseout", function() {
    div.html(" ").style("display", "none");
  });

// draw inner text
svg.append("text")
  .text('60%')
  .attr("class", "donut-inner-val")
  //.attr("x", radius/12 - 30)
  //.attr("y", radius/12 - 10);

svg.append("text")
  .text('in progress')
  .attr("class", "donut-inner-text")
  .attr("x", (radius / 12) - 35)
  .attr("y", (radius / 12) + 10);
```

**[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/betasquirrel/6zn5rno9/17/)**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this Code**

```
  .on('click', function(d, i) {
        d3.selectAll(".foreground").classed('selected', false);
    if(d3.select(this).classed("active")){
        d3.select(this)
      .classed('selected', true);
    }else{
    d3.selectAll(".foreground").classed("active", false);
    d3.select(this).classed("active",true);

            d3.select(this)
      .classed('selected', true);
    }
  })
```

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/6zn5rno9/24/)

Comment: Despite this being a good answer, there is no jQuery in OP's code or tags.

Comment: As expected, the updated one handles the switching by applying css class. Perfect!